# Using a DLL written in/for C++ in a C# program

Tags: c#, dll, interop, wrapper

I'm writing a program for my college's chemistry department, incorporating three separate devices - a force sensor, a Z-axis nanopositioner stage, and a XYZ axis picomotor stage. I have to incorporate these three devices into a single program and have them communicate with one another. I've already successfully incorporated the force sensor and Z-axis stage. They both came with DLLs ready-made for C#. Since I'm writing a GUI program and I'm already fairly familiar with C#, this was the natural choice.

However, the XYZ stage's DLL was written for C++. I'm not really sure how to get this DLL to work in my program. I can't add a reference to it in Visual Studio because it's not compatible, and the header files that come with it that expose the functions in the DLL were written for C++.

- [sio_util.h](http://pastebin.com/5NjTS0T9)
- [stepper.h](http://pastebin.com/EudNQdfs)
- [servo.h](http://pastebin.com/X3jT7KSw)
- [ldcncom.h](http://pastebin.com/Rx5qTYyK)

I have a basic understanding of the process. In the ldcncom.h header, there'es a function written as so:

```
DLLENTRY(int)  LdcnInit(char *portname, unsigned int baudrate);
```

I rewrote it as this in my C# program:

```
[DllImport("Ldcnlib.dll", EntryPoint = "LdcnInit")]
public static extern int LdcnInit(char[] portname, uint baudrate);
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it "worked" insofar that it was able to read the function from the DLL and perform it's duty... just not completely right because it's still missing all of the other functions.

But I'm not sure how to do the rest. For instance, in sio_util.h, there's a function with a return type of HANDLE, another with a return type of DWORD, and I'm not very familiar with these and don't know how to make it work in C#.

I've heard of stuff like interop, wrappers, C++/CLI, but that's a little beyond me at the moment (still somewhat new to all of this), so any advice on how to do this process would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I'm not sure how to do the rest. For instance, in sio_util.h, there's a function with a return type of HANDLE, another with a return type of DWORD, and I'm not very familiar with these and don't know how to make it work in C#.

[`DWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx) is a 32 bit unsigned integer, so you'd use `UInt32` (`uint`) to represent that.

A [`HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a `void*`, or any pointer, so you'd typically use `IntPtr` to represent a `HANDLE` in C#.

The [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page lists most of the Windows standard types, which should provide a good starting point on figuring out the P/Invoke types you'd need.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I could essentially repeat the process I did for that one function (ldcninit), rewriting it as DllImport etc, for each other function and arrive at a good spot?

Comment: @RobertJosephDacunto Yes - that's the idea - you just create a `[DllImport]` declaration to match each method.  I'd, personally, wrap this into a nice C# class when you're done, so the usage is "clean", though.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I have a quick follow-up: 

all the functions are broken up over several header files for the original dll. Should I throw it all under one single class in my new program? I ran all the code through this program  that the user Balachandra provided me below, and it produced this: 

`http://pastebin.com/nHUMkAit`

I'm not sure if this the proper set up, if all the functions will be exposed to each other, etc. Thanks again

Comment: @RobertJosephDacunto I typically put these in an internal (not public) type, and name it "NativeMethods" or something similar.  I then will wrap the related, needed methods in a clean C# class (which may implement IDisposable to handle cleanup, as needed).  This makes usage far cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert more C++ data types into C# and find it time consuming, there is great tool "P/Invoke Signature Generator" which makes this job easy. [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx) is good article about how to use it.

You have to copy the native method signature and the tool generates the C# signature.

Comment: Thank you for the link. The program seems very useful. I downloaded it and went to the third tab (SigImp Translate Snippet), which seems to be for my own code. I typed in one of the functions and clicked generate, but I get an error that says "Error: Expected token of type ParenClose but found IntKeyword instead." Perhaps I'm using it wrong.

Comment: what is native method signature? can you share it?

Comment: I'm probably using the program wrong, but in the open file (ldcncom.h), there's a bunch of functions I want to "convert". This is one of them: 
    `DLLENTRY(int)  LdcnInit(char *portname, unsigned int baudrate);`

Comment: Try just "int LdcnInit(char *portname, unsigned int baudrate);" ignore the DLLENTRY(int), it should work.